# Call Config::set to change database in Lumen 5.4? (Using Eloquent)

Tags: database, laravel, lumen

I have a small application in Lumen which should handle multiple databases based on the request URL. To make this possible in the first place I've created a folder **/config/** and a config-file called **/config/database.php**. Here is the code and I added some comments to show what I exactly need to do.

```
<?php
return [
    'migrations' => 'home',
    'default' => 'home',
    'connections' => [
        // This is the default option and its needed to check if the "client" exists.
        'home' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'home',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],    

        // When the client is found in the "home" connection, I'd like to continue with this database settings as default.
        'client' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'client_', // There is one database per client which in the end will look like this: "client_******", so I have to add this using Config:set...
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
    ],
];
```

I have to call `Config::set` to change these settings but it doesnt seem to be available on Lumen. How can i change these settings (the **default database connection** and its **database**)

I hope there is a way to make this possible. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

To set and edit your configuration use the "config" helper method with an array as argument.

Example:

```
config(['database.default' => 'your_connection']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a query you can use as follows:

$connectionClient =  DB::connections('client');
 $connectionHome =  DB::connections('home');

I hope have helped.

Comment: Hi Ricardo. Thanks for your answer. This would be great but I still have to change the database of the connection "client" to "client_****" because every client has his own database. Do you know how I could set the database dynamically?